# Using CSS transforms to translate/rotate sprite using arrow key inputs. Problem updating position

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-transforms

I am trying to control a Sprite using the arrow keys (UP/DOWN for Translation & LEFT/RIGHT for Rotation).

I need the sprite to **translate in the direction it has been rotated in**.
The issue is that when the sprite is rotated after the sprite has been translated, the position of the sprite resets to where it was originally. I have tried using one div for rotation and one div for translation to no success.

The problem I am facing is a little different to the usual "moving div around screen" issue because I need to move the div at angles and continue to move at that angle.

I feel I am overlooking a simple solution, I would really appreciate if someone could point me in the right direction! Is there an easier alternative to what I am attempting to do that someone could make me aware of?

I have created a JSFiddle to demonstrate what is going on:

[CSS transform sprite fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/evandarcy/cyv0j1du/14/)

```js
var r = document.getElementById("image2");

document.addEventListener("keyup", checkKeyUp);
document.addEventListener("keydown", checkKey);

var trany = 0;
var rotate = 0;

function checkKey(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    if (e.keyCode == '38') {
        // up arrow
        trany = trany-1;
        r.style.transform = 'rotate('+rotate+'deg)translateY('+trany+'vmin)';
    }
    else if (e.keyCode == '40') {
        // down arrow
        trany = trany+1;
        r.style.transform = 'rotate('+rotate+'deg)translateY('+trany+'vmin)';
    }
    else if (e.keyCode == '37') {
       // left arrow
        rotate = rotate-.8;
        r.style.transform = 'translateY('+trany+'vmin)rotate('+rotate+'deg)';
    }
    else if (e.keyCode == '39') {
      // right arrow
        rotate = rotate+.8;
        r.style.transform = 'translateY('+trany+'vmin)rotate('+rotate+'deg)';
    }
}

function checkKeyUp(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    if (e.keyCode == '38') {
        // up arrow
    }
    else if (e.keyCode == '40') {
        // down arrow
    }
    else if (e.keyCode == '37') {
       // left arrow
       r.style.transform = 'translateY('+trany+'vmin)rotate('+rotate+'deg)';
    }
    else if (e.keyCode == '39') {
      // right arrow
      r.style.transform = 'translateY('+trany+'vmin)rotate('+rotate+'deg)';
    }
}
```

```css
#myAnimation {
  top:250px;
  left:250px;
  position: absolute;
}
#image2 {
  width:40%
}

img {
  width: 30%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<body>

<div id ="myContainer">
  <div id="image1" style="height:300px;width:500px; background- 
    color:red;"></div>
</div>

<div id ="myAnimation">
    <image id="image2" src="https://banner2.kisspng.com/20180415/pge/kisspng-arrow-desktop-wallpaper-symbol-clip-art-up-arrow-5ad37ddc82f384.4572004515238097565364.jpg" style="bottom:0px;width:10%"></image>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Tried to open the link and I get dialog containing "IE is not supported", my IE version is  11.0.9600.19155, add some error handling to your script.

Comment: That's now fixed, however instead of a dialog, now it displays "IE is not supported" in the center of the browser window.

Comment: The "Run code snippet" works as long as you go to Full page.

Comment: Looks like you are only tracking y and using y for both x and y.

Comment: You are switching between `px` and `vmin` units for your `translateY` value  - you sure that’s what you want …?

Comment: I have changed all to vmin, thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1):

To fix this problem we need to understand how transform works. It does each step one by one. If we want, for example to move diagonally, first we need to rotate, then translate. If we want to make the next move, our previous steps need to be saved. If we don't remember them, the arrow will be animated from the beginning.
So, on each animation end (key up) we need to save all the previous steps.
The next step is all the previous steps + translate/rotate.

Here is your code that I think is working correctly:

```
var r = document.getElementById("image2");

document.addEventListener("keyup", checkKeyUp);
document.addEventListener("keydown", checkKey);

var saved_moves = '';

var trany = 0;
var rotate = 0; 

function checkKey(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    if (e.keyCode == '38') {
        // up arrow
        trany = trany-1;
        r.style.transform = saved_moves + 'translateY('+trany+'vmin)';
    }
    else if (e.keyCode == '40') {
        // down arrow
        trany = trany+1;
        r.style.transform = saved_moves + 'translateY('+trany+'vmin)';
    }
    else if (e.keyCode == '37') {
       // left arrow
        rotate = rotate-2;
        r.style.transform = saved_moves + 'rotate('+rotate+'deg)';
    }
    else if (e.keyCode == '39') {
      // right arrow
        rotate = rotate+2;
        r.style.transform = saved_moves + 'rotate('+rotate+'deg)';
    }
}

function checkKeyUp(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    if (e.keyCode == '37' || e.keyCode == '38' || e.keyCode == '39' || e.keyCode == '40') {
        // every arrow
        saved_moves = r.style.transform;
        // reset trany and rotate values
        trany = 0;
        rotate = 0;
    }
}
```

You can check this jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/cyv0j1du/49/

**EDIT** 
Becouse the solution above would create a very long transform, I've came up with different solution. When you release the key, app is reading the matrix value, and then it changes the arrow top and left value. Now only rotate value is remembered.

```
// Based on the absolute position you've chosen
var left = 250;
var top = 250;

function checkKeyUp(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    if (e.keyCode == '37' || e.keyCode == '38' || e.keyCode == '39' || e.keyCode == '40') {

        var matrix = window.getComputedStyle(r).getPropertyValue('transform');

        matrix = matrix.slice(0, -1);

        var values = matrix.split(',');
            var x = values[4];
        var y = values[5];

                top += parseInt(y);
        left += parseInt(x);

                r.style.top = top + 'px';
                r.style.left = left + 'px';

        r.style.transform = 'rotateZ('+rotate+'deg)'; 

                trany = 0;
    }
}
```

I've also deleted #myAnimation

```
#image2 {
  width: 20%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 250px;
  left: 250px;
}
```

so I've deleted the div

```
 <image id="image2" src="https://banner2.kisspng.com/20180415/pge/kisspng-arrow-desktop-wallpaper-symbol-clip-art-up-arrow-5ad37ddc82f384.4572004515238097565364.jpg" style="bottom:0px;width:10%"></image>
```

You can check how it works here:
https://jsfiddle.net/w1ox240m/57/

Comment: intresting solution but we will end with a HUGE tranform after a lot of movements

Comment: Hey man, thanks so much for this! It helps A LOT. I completely understand the code too, it's a smart solution, thanks again.

Comment: How much will the added transforms affect performance though?

Comment: @evandarcy you can test and see. It depends on how the browser will handle this, A big transform will at the end be converted to one matrix, so you need to see if the conversion is taking a lot of time or not

Comment: I'm thinking now about better solution, that will only save rotate value. It will use some math.

Comment: @evandarcy Just fyi, if I do keep the "up" (or "down") arrow key, and then press the "left" (or "right") arrow key, the position is reseted. I know that you were not asking about this, but depending of what you are trying to achieve, it can be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

what you want to achieve is to move your element **independently** from its previous state and this cannot be achieved using only transform since transform always consider the initial state in order to move your element.

An idea is to consider using `bottom`/`left` to move the element and use only transform to rotate the element. The angle of rotation will define how you will adjust the bottom and left properties:

```js
var r = document.getElementById("image2");

document.addEventListener("keydown", checkKey);

var rotate = 0;
var left=0;
var bottom= 0;

function checkKey(e) {
  e = e || window.event;
  if (e.keyCode == '38') {
    // up arrow
    r.style.left = left + Math.sin(rotate*Math.PI/180)  + 'px';
    r.style.bottom = bottom + Math.cos(rotate*Math.PI/180) + 'px';
  } else if (e.keyCode == '40') {
    // down arrow
    r.style.left = left - Math.sin(rotate*Math.PI/180)  + 'px';
    r.style.bottom = bottom -  Math.cos(rotate*Math.PI/180) + 'px';
  } else if (e.keyCode == '37') {
    // left arrow
    rotate = rotate - .8;
    r.style.transform = 'rotate(' + rotate + 'deg)';
  } else if (e.keyCode == '39') {
    // right arrow
    rotate = rotate + .8;
    r.style.transform = 'rotate(' + rotate + 'deg)';
  }
  left = parseFloat(r.style.left);
  bottom = parseFloat(r.style.bottom);
}
```

```css
#image2 {
  width: 40px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<img id="image2" src="https://banner2.kisspng.com/20180415/pge/kisspng-arrow-desktop-wallpaper-symbol-clip-art-up-arrow-5ad37ddc82f384.4572004515238097565364.jpg" style="left:0;bottom:0;">
```

Comment: Another nice solution, thank you Temani. I had attempted to implement this before but gave up as I did not like the movement at an angle. It is not smooth and kind of wiggles a pixel or two side to side as it moves.

Comment: @evandarcy yes, changing left/bottom will not be as smooth as translate but it remains another way that we can probably improve ;)

Comment: of course! I appreciate your answer, it's very helpful :-)